# How can I pass flags to node through browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to fix a long existing problem when using `npm link` together with `peerDependencies`. Since node `6.3.0`, there is a [`--preserve-symlinks`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/cli.html#cli_preserve_symlinks) flag that one can use to resolve module requires using the symlinked path.

I successfully applied the flag to my project like this: `node --preserve-symlinks app.js`

Now how can I achieve the same using browserify? The following does not work:
`node --preserve-symlinks ./node_modules/.bin/browserify app.js > out.js`. I end up with my module not being found, which means the flag doesn't get applied to node.

Comment: Where are you when you run this command? And can you copy/paste whole error?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue...

Comment: @Merott I ended up using an environment variable like this in front of my browserify command: `NODE_PATH=./node_modules`. That way I don't need the preserve-symlinks flag and browserify will find peerDependencies with symlinked modules anyway, yay!